# Is there a way to increase the amount of species allowed in a phylogenetic tree for my analysis?

Tags: r, phylogeny

```r
Programs used include:
library(phytools)
library(adephylo)
library(geiger)
library(nlme)
library(evomap)
library(caper)
library(scales)
library(coda)
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_light())
library(HDInterval)

df <- rbind(amphibian, turtles)
df <- rbind(df, crocs)
df <- rbind(df, squamata)
df <- rbind(df, bird)
df <- rbind(df, mammal)


> str(df)
'data.frame':   1721 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ species: chr  "Ambystoma_cingulatum" "Ambystoma_dumerilii" "Ambystoma_jeffersonianum" "Ambystoma_macrodactylum" ...
 $ diel   : chr  "NOC" "NOC" "ARR" "NOC" ...
 $ MaxDIU : chr  "NOC" "NOC" "DIU" "NOC" ...
 $ MaxNOC : chr  "NOC" "NOC" "NOC" "NOC" ...
 $ Tp     : num  18.7 17.9 17.8 21 8.3 ...

> summary(df)
   species              diel              MaxDIU         
 Length:1721        Length:1721        Length:1721       
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
                                                         
                                                         
                                                         
    MaxNOC                Tp       
 Length:1721        Min.   : 6.00  
 Class :character   1st Qu.:32.40  
 Mode  :character   Median :36.50  
                    Mean   :34.91  
                    3rd Qu.:39.60  
                    Max.   :44.60  

> summary(myTree)

Phylogenetic tree: myTree 

  Number of tips: 0 
  Number of nodes: 
  No branch lengths.
  No root edge.
  Tip labels: 
              
  No node labels

> data <- comparative.data(data = df, phy = myTree, 
      names.col = "species")
```

Error in tabulate(phy$edge[, 1]) : 'bin' must be numeric or a factor

I keep receiving this error as I continue with my analysis and it I think it is tied to `myTree` being to large to be completed read with over 1000+ species but I'm not sure. How do I edit the phylogenetic tree so that I no longer receive this error and am able to use my comparative method? I'm beginning to think it has something to do with how my tree has uploaded after receiving results from the summary...

I'm not entirely certain which program operates Comparative.data function due to following an example that was provided to me (I have not used this function in a prior circumstance).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! if you have 1000+ species (and your problem is indeed caused by a too-large data set), it will be hard to come up with a [mcve], but could you please at least edit your question to show us (1) what package (or other source) `comparative.data()` comes from and (2) the results of `str(df)` or `summary(df)` **and** `summary(myTree)` (please include these as cut-and-pasted text, not as screenshots/images ...)

Comment: Thank you Ben for your input. I was wondering what information is most necessary to answer the question! I will get it edited with that info.

Comment: Based on the function description [link](https://rdrr.io/cran/caper/src/R/comparative.data.R), maybe try: `df$species <- as.factor(df$species);  data <- comparative.data(data = df, phy = myTree, 
      names.col = "species")

Comment: Something looks weird about your tree too.  `summary()` is reporting that it has zero tips?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure what happened there.. going to troubleshoot that first and see if its causing the issue.

Comment: both the tree and the fact that "species" should be a factor (which is easy to fix, as @markhogue showed) should be fixed before proceeding ...

Comment: That was it... I didn't upload as nexus instead I did csv.. simple error. Apologies for the time waste!